# Rows with Revenue =0, how do I show the 0?

Tags: mysql

The following code shows all our customers that have made purchases since our database was created and how much money they have spent. There are a couple customers that have not made purchases since we implemented the new database but they are not appearing when I run this code. I have looked around this site for similar examples but the solutions are too complex for me.
There is also a customers table that shows the results for all of our 'n' customers, that table connects to the orders table through customerID. Not sure if that will help.

```
select t3.CustomerID, sum(Revenue) as Revenue
from
(
select orderid, sum(UnitPrice*quantity) as Revenue from [Order Details]
group by OrderID
)t1
inner join
(
select customerid,orderid from orders
)t3
on t1.orderid=t3.orderid
group by t3.CustomerID
```

Comment: You want an `OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want this rather simpler query:

```
  select c.CustomerID, sum(od.UnitPrice * od.quantity) as Revenue
  from customers c left outer join
       orders o
       on o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId left outer join
       `Order Details` od 
       on od.OrderId = o.OrderId
  group by c.CustomerID;
```

Comment: Exactly, I added a [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc941/3/0) if you're interested in playing around with this query.

Comment: @SimonKrenger . . . Here is a slightly revised SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/976e4/2) that includes the unpleasant table name from the OP (`Order Details` instead of `order_details`).